# HERE Javascript API - Map layer doesn't load properly on Safari and iOS

Tags: here-api

I am creating a FileMaker GO solution for iOS, in this solution I am using a web viewer that is showing a map with some markers by using HERE JavaScript API.
When I use the solution on Mac OS X, everything is fine, I see the map, the markers, I can click on them and it opens Map application as expected.
But on iOS, the map remains grey it doesn't seems to load, but I can see the markers and click on them.
Something else, I noticed the same behavior on Safari with Mac OS X when I look at the examples on the HERE API Developer website, but with Chrome or Firefox everything work properly, here is one of the examples :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/markers-on-the-map

Does anyone have an idea ?

Here the html/javascript code I am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  </head>
<body style="position: relative" >
  <div id="mapContainer" style="position: fixed ; top: 0 ; bottom: 0 ; left : 0 ; right : 0 ; background: grey" />
  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >


  /* DATA RECEIVED FROM FILEMAKER */
  
  /*  JSON array with full addresses */
  
  var jsonInterventions = [{"estExecutee":0,"idIntervention":"E1630517-3EFF-DD4F-981F-A6E703BB8798","jsonattributes":1,"lat":48.81266,"lng":2.42228,"ordre":1},{"estExecutee":0,"idIntervention":"22E00113-A7F6-4DC7-95FB-252AB0A1E028","jsonattributes":1,"lat":48.721023,"lng":2.538195,"ordre":1}] ;

  /* Total number of addresses */
  
  var totalInterventions = 2 ;

  /* Additional info on the FileMaker file in order to use the FMP protocol */
  
  var AdresseServeur = '$' ;
  var NomFichier = 'Mosaïc' ;
  var ApiKey = 'XXXXXX';    
  
  /* FUNCTIONS */
  
  function GetSVGMarkup(color,colorfont,ordre){
  return '<svg height="32" width="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" aria-labelledby="title" aria-describedby="desc" role="img" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">'+
                  '<path data-name="layer1" d="M32 62c0-17.1 16.3-25.2 17.8-39.7A18 18 0 1 0 14 20a17.7 17.7 0 0 0 .2 2.2C15.7 36.8 32 44.9 32 62z" fill="' + color + '"></path>'+
                  '<text x="32" y="32" font-size="20pt" ' + 'font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" ' + 'fill="'+ colorfont +'">'+ ordre +'</text>'+
                  '</svg>';
  }

  /* Display markers on the map */
  function AffichageMarqueurs(platform) {

    /* For each address */
    for(var i=0 ; i<totalInterventions ; i++){

      var color = jsonInterventions[i].estExecutee ? "#AAAAAA" : "#1b468d",
      colorfont = jsonInterventions[i].estExecutee ? "black" : "white",
          ordre = jsonInterventions[i].ordre,
      svgMarkup = GetSVGMarkup(color,colorfont,ordre),
           icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup);

      /* Creation of a marker used the sent coordinates */
      marker = new H.map.Marker(jsonInterventions[i], {icon: icon});
      groupePoints.addObject(marker);
      marker.setZIndex(i);
      
      /* We keep the address ID for later */
      var idIntervention = jsonInterventions[i].idIntervention ;    
      marker.setData(idIntervention);

      /* Marker added to the map */
      map.addObject(groupePoints);

      map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({bounds: groupePoints.getBoundingBox()});
    }
  }


  function CasErreur(error) {
     /* nothing */
  } 
  
      // Initialize the platform object:
  var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': ApiKey,
     useHTTPS: true
  });

    // Get the default map types from the Platform object:
    //var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

  /* Creation of the layer seen by default */
  var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
    tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
    ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
  });


    // Instantiate the map:
    var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
            zoom: 4,
            center: { lng: 5, lat: 50 },
            pixelRatio
        });



    // Enable the event system on the map instance:
    var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

    // Add event listeners:
    map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
       // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
       console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type);
    });

    // Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object:
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

    // Create the default UI:
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers,'fr-FR');
    
    /* Setting of a groupe of points (group of addresses) */
    var groupePoints = new  H.map.Group()

    /* display list of addresses on the map */
    AffichageMarqueurs(platform);

    /* Center the map in order to see all the points displayed */
    map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({bounds: groupePoints.getBoundingBox()});

    /* If the user clicks on a marker */
    groupePoints.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {

    /* Open in Filemaker a FM card model with additional info on the clicked address */
    var lienFmp = "fmp://" + AdresseServeur + "/" + NomFichier + "?script=FMP - Open GPSAPP onClick"+
        "&$idIntervention=" + evt.target.getData() ;

    window.open(lienFmp, "_blank"); 
  }, false);

        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 17/07/2020 :

Here is a screenshot from Safari web inspector showing some errors ( the page I debugged is from the link above :

[image]

Comment: When you debug with the Safari web inspector, do you see anything?

Comment: So I checked with both Safari web inspector and Chrome inspector. With the Developper Here Api example link from my post, both of them return 2 same errors "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", on Chrome the map appears. But on safari there are 8 errors with tiles of the map like "Tangram [error]: tile load error for tile with key 0/4/3/3/3 and id 32: undefined" I will edit my post to put some screenshots !

Comment: So the errors loading the map files can be ignored. For the other ones - that's the console, what do you see in the network tab of devtools?